# Is there a pyvenv command to list all virtual environments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used 'python3 -m venv ' sometime back and created a virtual environment with it but I am unable to retrieve its location. Is there a way to list all virtual environments that were created using the pyvenv command ?

Comment: Is `pyenv virtualenvs` what you're after?

Comment: No actually pyvenv is what I have pyenv is different.